# honda accord sometimes wont start

Tags: honda, starting, accord

I have a starting problem with my 1999 Honda accord, 1 in every 50 starts for example the car will turn over but fails to start, I repeatedly turn the key then the crank slows down but still doesn't fire. it happened today at about 12 o clock gone out now and its started first time any ideas what this could be? thanks

Answer (score 2):

An intermittant like you have described can be an absolute nightmare to track down. A visual inspection of the engine management system for loom damage or corrosion, contamination or oiling of plugs. You can connect a data logger onto the vehicle to record any mis-function when it does not start. A OEM scanner may also reveal the fault. Main suspects for me would be crankshaft sensor, camshaft sensor, or engine management fuses or relays.

Answer (score 2):

Could have an idle air control valve Issue, if valve sticks open will cause a big vacuum leak which would cause a no start. Next time it happens try taping litely on valve if starts replace valve

Comment: You could really flesh out your answer by providing basic information about what you are talking about and how one would find the IAC on any given engine.

Comment: Idle control valve is located on the back side of intake manifold  by the throttle body or you could simply go to